# Velocity Apache accessing element in map that doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, velocity

I am trying to extract a string from a header attached to a request from the client like so.

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "type": "Query",
        "resolver": "apiContext",
        "arguments":  $utils.toJson($context.arguments),
        "contextToken": "$context.request.headers["context-token"]"
    }
}
```

If the client passes the header, it is able to extract the contents whether it contains null, undefined, a numerical, or string value. However, when I try to hit this request without the header (meaning no contect-token header), the value that gets passedto my AWS lambda handler contains  `"contextToken": "$context.request.headers["context-token"]"` and I get an error  `Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries at [Source: (String)"`. I am struggling to figure out how to pass the value of the header only if it exists in the headers map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Velocity silent reference:

```
"contextToken": "$!context.request.headers['context-token']"
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The log of that argument in my Lambda is the literal `$context.request.headers.context-token`

Comment: hey i take that back. We had another vtl template doing the same thing and that was causing the erroneous log. Thank you so much for your suggestion.